# How to handl enum fields in phpunit / cakephp?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, simpletest

Background:

I am trying to unit test a cakephp app. The app was built without unit testing. I want to add unit test so that future development can be structured.

The app uses a number of enum columns and since cakephp does not support enum columns I can not proceed to write unit tests for the existing code. I see some people suggested converting enum to tinyint or varchar. I would have tried that solution if enum fields contain only two options (e.g. enabled/disable, true/false , active/inactive ) as it would'nt require code change but for enum fields with more values its not an easy solution.

Question:

Is there a simpler way that I can write unit test for a pre-build app with minimal changes ?

Answer (score 0):

If you google, you fill find several different - and well working - approaches.
I personally favor class constants and static methods to easily access them (including i18n): http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

But you can also use EnumBehaviors or ArrayDatasources etc.
There are lots of other solutions if you google for it.

Important for me is, that the first solution allows you to use custom bake templates and bake your code already enum-ready with all the enum dropdowns in it. And also, that it is very fast since it does not need any db lookups to form the int value into a user-friendly and possibly translated string value.
You can also use subset enums (some instead of all available) and re-order them as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your response - BTW I did googled it before asking the question ... 

I am exploring the first solution - thanks a lot.